# Setting import function to simplify the import process in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

Here is my question.

I use ipython notebook for daily data processing and analysis. When I create a new notebook, some essential packages must be imported first. After long-time  accumulation, some process are interlinked and oriented to different task.

I can summarize the nature of my common project into these classes:

- Data processing(`numpy`,`scipy`,etc. eg, `from scipy import interpolate`)
- Data tiding(`Pandas`, `csv`, etc)
- Dealing with scientific format data(`netcdf4`,`pyhdf`.eg: `from osgeo import gdal`)

  - Basic plotting(`Matplotlib`,`Pylab`)
  - Plotting attribute adjust. eg:

    ```
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
    from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation, UniformTriRefiner   
    from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
    ```

...

I often meet different tasks with similar working processes. The packages and some user defined function are the same(For example, I often write the correlation function myself for faster speed than `pandas.corr`). I had to search for past notebooks to find  relevant code and copy them. Sometimes, I forget where to find them but I always know my **working pattern**.

#### So, my question begins

Is it possible to generate an meta-function library which will represent these  features:

1. When I first work out some problem, I'll devise it into a pervasive function with broad import (one simple case, one user defined colormap can be stored for use another day)
2. When I use an brand new notebook, I don't need to reproduce the import process (for now, I had to write 41 lines dealing with regular work, and some of them are not essential for this project). I just need to think about every **working pattern**  I had created and import them easily!

For example: Looping and reading specific lines in .csv file can be reproduced easily.

If it's possible, the notebook can be neat and clear!

Comment: Surely it's clearer to have your dependencies written there clearly at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible.  You'll just need to understand the Python import rules- any package that appears as a sub-directory of your PYTHONPATH environment variable can be imported with a traditional import statement.

So, say you had a directory called ~/python/mypatterns containing your set of utility code.  You would add ~/python to your PYTHONPATH, and ensure that there is a file called **init**.py (it doesn't need any contents) in that directory.  So...

```
# Setup your environment
touch ~/mypatterns/__init__.py
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:~/python
# command to start your notebook...

# in your notebook...
from mypatterns.myfile import myfunction
...
```